# Tracking changes in Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, editor, listener

My aim is to register some kind of listener which will track changes in the text being edited in a text editor (in fact, CEditor from CDT). What is the proper type of listener, and to which object should I attach it?

As an alternative, I would be content if the listener only tracked user's save action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most general would be the `IDocumentListener` set up by `IDocument.addDocumentListener`

You should be able to get the document for an editor with something like:

```java
ITextEditor textEditor = (ITextEditor)part;

IEditorInput input = textEditor.getEditorInput();

IDocumentProvider provider = textEditor.getDocumentProvider();

IDocument document = provider.getDocument(input);
```